# Multiple toggle on mobile version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello i have a footer navigation (for desktop) with 3 Ul, i want transform each ul in a toggle on mobile version, how can do it? 
thx in advance

```
   <footer class="footer">
     <div class="wrapper">
      <nav class="footer-navigat">

        <ul>
          <li><h2>Title</h2></li>
           <li><a href="#">prod1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li><h2>Title 3</h2></li>
           <li><a href="#">prod1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
        </ul>
          <ul>
          <li><h2>Title 3</h2></li>
           <li><a href="#">prod1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: what you mean by toggle?

Comment: also please post what all efforts you have taken so far...!

Comment: I assume he wants each list to be hidden in an accordion

Comment: Have you looked at the checkbox hack?

Comment: Hexana, i know checkbox hack, but when im on desktop site, the menu it's classic ul list, just change on the mobile with accordion.

Comment: Ok then you need to look at media queries and set breakpoints for the menu to display at full boona above 480px and fall into toggle/accordion mode below 480px (or whatever width you define in your responsive styles).

Comment: but with checkbox hack, i have to change my html,with a lot of code, and when i have 1 checked list and click on the second the first remain open....   the best solution it's jquery no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extremely basic answer to your issue.

You need to restructure your html so that you have a sub `ul` in the previous ones like so:

```
<ul>
    <li class="clickme"><h2>Title</h2></li>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a href="#">prod1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Then if you wrap the following in a media query so that they only kick in at your mobile width, they will hide your sub nav:

```
.subnav {display: none;}
.show-nav {display:block;}
```

Finally, the following jquery will allow you to toggle a class that changes the display properties of the sub-nav:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('.clickme');
    var subnav = $('.sub-nav');

    button.on('click',function(){
       subnav.toggleClass('show-nav'); 
    });
});
```

This is all here in a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/uuL2wyLk/

---

EDIT:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uuL2wyLk/2/

This fiddle shows the `display:none;` property only being applied when the window width is less than 500px. When the page is loaded, the script will check to see if the `.sub-nav` has `display:none;`, and if it does, will allow the accordion script to run.

This means that when the page is loaded on mobile, the display property will be present due to the media query, which in turn allows the script, but on desktop, the property will not be present and the accordion script will not run.

If you see the new fiddle and shrink the result section down small, and then hit run, you will see that the accordion works. If you make the result section larger and hit run again, the accordion will not fire.

Here is the fiddle again: http://jsfiddle.net/uuL2wyLk/2/

---

EDIT 2:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uuL2wyLk/3/

I have updated the fiddle to allow multiple menus. I have changed the html so that the `<li>` contains the sub nav as well as the click button, like so:

```
<li>
    <h2 class="clickme">Title</h2>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a href="#">prod1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

With the jquery, you can then make it so that on click of the title, it will find the sibling `.sub-nav` and apply the `.shownav` to it. Below is a snippet from the code:

```
button.on('click',function(){
    $(this).siblings(subnav).toggleClass('show-nav'); 
});
```

For all of the code to make this work, see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uuL2wyLk/3/

Comment: thx for comment, but the problem it's the same, because i need to accordion only on mobile.

Comment: If you use a media query to apply `display: none` to the `.sub-nav` at your mobile width, you can a jquery if statement to check for the property and then allow the accordion code. See this link: https://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries   Ihave updated the answer above.

Comment: yes i understand, and it's good code, but just one problem, if i have 2 or more ul, all list are open or close.  So if i click on the first ul list, the script opens all list..

Comment: I've updated the answer again for you

Comment: @Armando has this solved your issue?

Comment: thx a lot, for your support!!

Answer (score 1):

This is as close to the behaviour you are suggesting.  You wrap your li in a content class and your title in a toggle class.  So when you click on a secondary menu item, the other menu item left open closes automatically.

**HTML**

```
    <ul>
      <li class="toggle">Title 1</li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod1</a></li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li class="toggle">Title 2</li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod1</a></li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
    </ul>
      <ul>
       <li class="toggle">Title 3</li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod1</a></li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod2</a></li>
       <li class="content"><a href="#">prod3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function() {
  $("li.content").hide();
  $("ul.navigation").delegate("li.toggle", "click", function() { 
  $(this).next().toggle("fast").siblings(".content").hide("fast");
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.toggle { color: blue; }
.content { border: slid 1px #ddd; padding: 5px; }
```

Here is an example fiddle with similar behaviour http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/K6TSv/1/

Comment: thx.   But with this  $("li.content").hide();   all content are hide on every size, i want hide the content only on determinate width